# Can I intercept 3rd party Vuejs component button click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use this [date range picker](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker) component in my app, however it doesn't provide any callback to catch the button click and run some function.

It provides a property `confirm`, that provides the "Ok" confirm button to click and accept the date range, however nothing to be able post process the click.

So I thought I could intercept the click of the component and try gather exactly what was clicked - in this case the OK button, and then run my functions.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to provide the expected $event

```
<date-picker v-model="range" range confirm :shortcuts="shortcuts" lang="en" @click.native="refreshReport(e)"></date-picker>
```

Methods

```
refreshReport() {
   console.log(e);
},
```

The `e` is not defined in this case, I even tried `e.native` and obviously that's not working.

I basically thought I could catch the event, check the element for the button class that the component uses and then run function if that is indeed what was clicked - can anyone help hack this ?

At the moment I'm trying to avoid forking it and trying to make it work for my requirements.

Comment: Wouldn't you refresh your report when `range` changes values? Also, you don't seem to have declared `e` as a parameter to `refreshReport`.

Comment: possibly - but not very elegant because it would run the event every click of the component and have to check the `range` each time - possibly multiple changes of the `range` would trigger refresh each time; just didn't like this option

Comment: Is range going to change apart from when you do the click you're looking for?

Comment: You haven't declared `e` as a parameter for the `refreshReport` method definition.